# How do I check if any letter in a string is included in another string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordle-game

```
if guess == wordleword.lower():
    print('Well Done!\n')
    print('You got it right!\n')
    print('Point added\n')
    points += 1
    with open('points.txt', 'w') as e:
        e.write(str(points))
    print('You now have ' + str(points))
result = "".join(set(guess))
if guess[0] in wordleword:
    print(guess.upper()[0] + ' is in the word')
if guess[1] in wordleword:
    print(guess.upper()[1] + ' is in the word')
if guess[2] in wordleword:
    print(guess.upper()[2] + ' is in the word')
if guess[3] in wordleword:
    print(guess.upper()[3] + ' is in the word')
if guess[4] in wordleword:
    print(guess.upper()[4] + ' is in the word')
```

How do I see if any character in result is included in the variable `wordleword`, and print to the terminal what letters are included?

Comment: what is `sf.dprint` ?

Comment: `sf.dprint` is a custom function I made that prints 1 letter at a time

Comment: please include that in the code. How do we know what's going on?

Comment: Your code isn't indented properly and will error immediately if you try to run it. Is that the problem you are asking about, or would you like to [edit] your question and fix it?

Comment: What is the objective of the code at least...

Comment: That is just from pasting it into stack overflow @khelwood all I would like to know is if there is a way to   see if any character in result is in a different variable called wordleanswer

Comment: @Edgar it is a snippet from a project to make a custom wordle in python

Comment: Does `if guess[0] in wordleword:` not already do what you want ?

Comment: try iterating through result and checking if the current character is in wordleword string

Comment: The answer to your question is right in the question itself. Use the `any()` function. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any `any(letter in wordleword for letter in result)`

Answer (score 0):

You can perform a set `intersection`.

```
w_set = set(wordleword.lower())
g_set = set(guess.lower())
print(sorted(w_set.intersection(g_set)))
```